# Manipulating background images using background-image

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to understand how to manipulate the ordering of layers, can someone please explain below why the background image is still above the text?

Can someone link to a resource that would teach me the layers and z-index properly?

Many thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/WqHjk/

CSS:

```
.trianglebackground {
    background-image:url('http://www.zwaldtransport.com/images/placeholders/placeholder1.jpg');
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.testtext{
    position:inline;
    z-index:1000;
}
.testbig{
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col testbig" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="trianglebackground"></div>
    <div class="col testtext" style="height:501px;">
        <div>some text here </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex.... while thinking of z-index please follow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because position is set to inline

So Make it absolute or relative

```
.testtext{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Take a look at this blog for more info about `z-index`

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, just Googling z-index will bring up plenty of stuff.

As for why your specific example isn't working, `position:inline` isn't valid. That should be position`: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to have in mind with z-index is that it's content dependent (as in it's at the mercy of the parents z-index) and that it works with positioned elements only and will not have an effect on static or inline elements.

Here's the correct CSS for your use case.

```
.trianglebackground {
  background-image:url('http://www.zwaldtransport.com/images/placeholders/placeholder1.jpg');
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
.col.d11 {
  z-index:2; 
  position:relative;
}
```